# How can I make the new python accept print without parentheses?

Tags: python, printing, command

Is there a way I can change my settings in python such that I can use

`print "hello world"` instead of the new `print ("hello world")` without installing an earlier package of python

Comment: @robbrit: not really; they want to use the old Python 2 syntax in Python 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way is to use python2.x instead of python3.x.  In python3.x, `print` is a function and there is no way to turn it back into a statement.

However, there are tools which can **transform** *most* python2 code to be compliant with python3.  Check out [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) which generally ships with python3 distributions.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks

Comment: Because it can be helpful to have a sympathetic ear, I agree this was a *mistake* in Python 3. The hobgoblins of consistency won this round.